# Cell2mat for cell arrays with numeric strings of different size in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

Hi I have a cell array which I want to convert to a matrix:

```
a = {'1.2'; '1.3'; '1.45'}
cell2mat(a)
```

Gives me the error:

```
Error using cat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in cell2mat (line 84)
            m{n} = cat(1,c{:,n});
```

Please help thank you!

Comment: You have a cell array of chars. Use [str2double](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html): `>> str2double(a)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cell2mat` fails because it's expecting numeric elements in the cell array, to be placed in a matrix. You have character arrays, not numeric elements, so you need to use `str2double` to convert them to doubles (the output is a matrix as desired).

```
a = {'1.2'; '1.3'; '1.45'};
out = str2double( a );
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try the below one:

```
a = {[1.2]; [1.3]; [1.45]}
cell2mat(a)
```

Comment: This doesn't take the same inputs as stated in the OP (i.e. you're inputting a cell of doubles, the OP has a cell of chars), so this doesn't answer the question.